# Is it better glBufferSubData or glMapBuffer

Tags: opengl

In order to update my uniform buffer objects I use `glBufferSubData`. Is it faster to use `glBufferSubData` or `glMapBuffer` with `glUnmapBuffer`?

Comment: That depends on the use case. You will have to test it for your case.

Comment: Ok I've done some tests and it seems that in my case `glMapBuffer` is way slower than `glBufferSubdata`: with `glMapBuffer` is have about 10FPS less than with `glBufferSubdata`

Comment: @zeb: It actually sounds like neither is appropriate if you are uploading data frequently enough for it to be that big a bottleneck. Look into multi-buffering or orphaning instead of creating resource contention (queued frames using your data vs. the current frame). The OpenGL Wiki [discusses this](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming) and would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 15):

The good thing about `glMapBuffer` is that you dont need to copy the data first in an array and then use `glBufferSubData` to fill the opengl buffer. With `glMapBuffer`, you can copy the data directly to part of memory which opengl will fetch to GPU when it is necessary. From my point of view, there `glMapBuffer` should be faster when you want to fill a big buffer which is going to be updated frequently. Also, how you are copying the data into the buffer between `glMapBuffer` and `glUnmapBuffer` is also important.

If show us the code which you are using the `glMapBuffer` and how big is the data, then we can judge easier. Anyway, in the end measurements can show you which one is better.

**UPDATE:** [OpenGL Insight Asynchronous Buffer Transfer Chapter](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~pcozzi/OpenGLInsights/OpenGLInsights-AsynchronousBufferTransfers.pdf). In this chapter, the `implicit synchronization` of `glMapBuffer` and `glSubBufferData` functions may be interesting for you.

Comment: Even with `glMapBuffer` one copies the data to a cpu memory array. The difference is only that `glBufferSubData` uses a user allocated array and with `glMapBuffer` the driver allocates it.

Comment: @BDL That's what I meant exactly. "you can copy the data directly to part of memory which opengl will fetch to GPU when it is necessary". by memory I meant system memory and not GPU memory. OpenGL always creates the buffers on system memory and fetch data on GPU when it is necessary.

Comment: But the conclusion is wrong: When copying a large memory segment to gpu `glMapBuffer` requires you to copy the data from it's original location to the mapped cpu memory (which can already be slow). Then the mapped memory is copied to gpu. With `glBufferSubData` the original memory can directly be copied to gpu.

Comment: @BDL Can you please provide me a reference for directly copying the data to gpu by `glBufferSubData`???

Comment: That's free to choose by the driver. In the end, it's not the point to discuss internal mechanisms, but to point out, that from my point of view there is no fact that would support that `"glMapBuffer should be faster when you want to fill a big buffer which is going to be updated frequently"`

Comment: OK! I can correct myself by saying `glMapBuffer` is more general. You can do what `glBufferSubData` is doing with `glMapBuffer` and even more. So, if you can use both, there should not be a difference between them but still `glMapBuffer` can do much more. So, if you just need to change the z values of your vertex coordinates, you should be able to do that faster with `glMapBuffer` as you just need to change the z component of the vertices.

Comment: @BDL Also, when I said it is faster, I meant it is faster because you do not need to create a buffer in user side and fill it with the data which you want to copy in the buffer. You can directly copy the data into the part of memory which opengl will transfer to gpu, directly.

If this chunk of data which is going to be copied is already in an array, and we dont need to create any additional array in user side, then `glMapData` and `glSubBufferData` should be identical.

Comment: I'm trying to implement orphaning with unsynchronized buffers and doing some tests. Once I have some news I'll report them

Comment: I've implemented orphaning with unsynchronized buffers and the time I spend updating my buffers now is really low. The problem now is that even with VSync deactivated my SwapBuffers function is slowing down everything. I mean, to draw my entire scene I spend 1.8ms and SwapBuffers takes 11672.8ms. Can't figure out why.

Comment: @mmostajab Like you say in your comment, "if you just need to change the z values of your vertex coordinates, you should be able to do that faster with glMapBuffer as you just need to change the z component of the vertices." As the mapped memory is system memory, not GPU memory, that the GPU will copy after, how does the GPU know which parts of the memory block to copy and which not. For example you map the buffer and get a pointer, and you go along x...y... z(change)...x...y...z(change), this memory is a block on the system RAM, it needs to be copied to the GPU, so again, how does it know?

Comment: The OpenGL Insight link is dead.