# Efficiently update Uniform Buffer Objects with instancing and culling

Tags: opengl

I've successfully updated my rendering engine to use uniform buffer objects and instancing.
The problem is that, since I do a first frustum culling pass every frame in order to know the objects I need to draw, I have to update the buffers every frame because the objects I draw could change every time, and this isn't the most efficient thing.

How could I make this more efficient?

The only thing I could think of is to not do the frustum culling so all the buffers remain static and I don't need to update them all the times, but not doing frustum culling I'd end up draw a lot of unnecessary objects.

Comment: How are you updating the buffers?

Comment: @Reto Koradi: Apparently this is related to zeb's other recent question, which has no accepted answer, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222574/is-it-better-glbuffersubdata-or-glmapbuffer).

Answer (score 2):

Updating uniform buffers is fairly cheap, to be honest. You are quite limited in size and that prevents you from doing anything too crazy.

What you need to focus on to make this efficient is actually accommodating incomplete commands that are queued up. You are more likely to run into problems where the driver/GPU is forced to stop working on the next frame/command due to poor data write patterns than you are to run into data transfer rate limitations. The problem is always going to be avoiding situations where you might write to portions of data that are still in use by the GPU (it is often working on data 1-2 frames behind the CPU).

You have multiple options depending on your target version, and the OpenGL Wiki has a [general overview](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming) of buffer streaming approaches.

---

You will have to do some performance testing to say for sure, but I suspect that CPU-side frustum culling combined with buffer orphaning of your instance UBO will give good results. Rather than reusing any data from previous frames, you would just stream the entire instance UBO from CPU to GPU each frame and let the GPU discard the old UBO when it finishes each frame.

Comment: Ok. So I will try to implementing orphaning with unsynchronized buffers as you and @mmostajab suggested me (in another post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222574/is-it-better-glbuffersubdata-or-glmapbuffer) )

Comment: Ok, I've updated my engine to use unsychronized buffers with orphaning and what I can see is that the time I spend on updating the buffers now is very very low and the time I spend rendering all the scene now is about 1.8ms. The thing that I don't understand is that even the time I spend preparing and drawing the scene is so low, I can't get more than 60fps even with VSync deactivated. Looking at the timeline I can see that the SwapBuffers function is eating all of my time